# What is the nth term of the lucky numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a sequence is generated like so:

1. start with the odd numbers
   $1,3,5,7,...$
2. start at $n=1$
3. take the next number $n$ from the sequence. So at the start of the first pass:
   sequence is $1,3,5,7,...$ and $n = 3$
4. remove every $n\mathrm{th}$ number from the list.
5. repeat from 3.

so the sequence would look like this after each of the first few passes:

$1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, ...$

$1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19, 21, 25, 27, 31, ...$

$1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 21, 25, 27, 31, ...$

$1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 21, 25, 31, ...$

The final sequence would be the sequence created after this process is gone through infinitely many times.

How could I define a relationship to get the $n\mathrm{th}$ term of the sequence, e.g.

$u_n =\ ...$

Comment: @Arthur oh wow, apparently they are the same thing. Is there an accepted formula for finding the nth lucky number?

Comment: Type A000959 in the OEIS.

Answer (score 5):

These are called the [lucky numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number). The only difference between your algorithm and wikipedia's is that wikipedia starts with all numbers, removes the even ones (because the first $n = 2$), and then they get to exactly where you start.

You can also look them up on the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000959). As for a formula, I don't think there's a good one. The elimination process seems to be way too erratic and unpredictable in the long run. Also, since the process is so close to the sieve of Eratosthenes, a concrete formula (and proof thereof) might also give general insight into the primes, and we *know* that that is difficult (see the Riemann hypothesis and the twin primes conjecture, for instance).